# Jquery Mobile Video Autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-website

I have a video that I display with an `autoplay` tag on my website.

```
<video autoplay class="header-image" preload>
        <source src="<?php print $theme_dir; ?>/img/mobile-banner.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <img class="img-responsive mobile" src="<?php print $theme_dir; ?>/img/main-banner-1-mobile.jpg"/>
</video>
```

I use JQuery to keep it repeating from a certain point on the video up to the end. I want this video to be autoplayed on mobile sites by default, in the following manner.

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var Vid = $('#front-page .mobile video.header-image');
        Vid.on('ended', function(){
            var thisVideo = Vid[0];
            thisVideo.currentTime = 7.9;
            thisVideo.play();
        });
    });
}(jQuery));
```

However, mobiles do not display this video. Is it possible to autoplay video, and if so, how do I write a script to force this mechanic?

In the event that it fails, what is the method I can employ to fall back into an image to display?

Comment: Show us what you have tried so far, SO is not a coding service

Comment: I am sorry. I will add the code what I have done so far.

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen have my edits improved the quality of my question? Thanks